# ApiException required Throwable, found CustomException

Tags: java, exception

I'm a little confused by this and hoping for some advice on how to resolve.

I've found a git repo that can help with my project, I've investigated the code, ran the tests and everything looks fine - it's essentially a wrapper for an api call negating the need for me to play with xml parsing and the like.

It has a custom exception, which in turn extends ApiException.  The inheritence is `CustomException>ApiException>Exception>Throwable.`

I've added this project to my own where it imported fine.  However I need to catch the exceptions it throws.  When I do this the compiler is complaining telling me that the types are incompatible and that it's `expecting Throwable but it found package.CustomException.`

Can anyone tell me what I've missed please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just on the offchance anyone stumbles on this same issue.  The answer was my own stupidity :)

I packaged the original code as a jar rather than a fat/uber jar so the ApiException class was missing.

Adding maven shade to the pom and packaging it again, adding new (much larger) jar to my project solved immediately.

One of those 'special' moments.

Comment: maybe you can select your own answer as valid so the ticket gets closed

Comment: I can't yet, there's a 2 day period.  Happy for you to copy/pasta and I'll mark that one so it gets closed down

Comment: it's not in my nature to say that is your own stupidity :)

Comment: @Conffusion :D :D  I won't take offence :)